# Need to access scope in ng-include directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I need to access the form data (`ng-model="name"`) in the **parent controller** *DynamicFormCtrl* . How do i access the data input in the form in the **DynamicFormCtrl** . I am not getting idea how to i access them.Though the data can be accessed in their own scopes.

```
 <body ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="DynamicFormCtrl as ctrl">
      <div>

    <button ng-click="ctrl.addForm(0)">Form One</button> //add form1
    <button ng-click="ctrl.addForm(1)">Form Two</button> //add form 2
    <button ng-click="ctrl.addForm(2)">Form Three</button>// add form 3
  </div>


  <div ng-repeat="form in ctrl.displayedForms track by $index"> //display form on button press



    <ng-include src="form"></ng-include> //Include from from the Script
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="form1.tpl.html">
    <label>
    {{name}}
      Form one is an input: <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    </label>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="form2.tpl.html">
    <label>
      Form two gives you choices: <input type="radio"/> <input type="radio"/>
    </label>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="form3.tpl.html">
    <button>Form three is a button</button>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("DynamicFormCtrl", function($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    $scope.form_name = $scope.name;
    console.log($scope.form_name);

    var forms = [
      "form1.tpl.html",
      "form2.tpl.html",
      "form3.tpl.html",
    ];

    ctrl.displayedForms = [];

    ctrl.addForm = function(formIndex) {
      ctrl.displayedForms.push(forms[formIndex]);
    }
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Add $scope.name = 'your name' in the controller

Comment: hey @MarcusH , that works for the local scope inside the form1.tpl.html but not on the the controller

Comment: Don't understand this question. Do you have a parent controller to DynamicFormCtrl? And you want to access the parents scope from the DynamicFormCtrl?

Comment: ng-include directive contains a Form which need to be accessed from **DynamicformCtrl** Controller . are you clear now , @MarcusH ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the controller-as syntax you should use ctrl.name in the input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name"/>
```

In the controller you can then use the input by using ctrl.name

You then also do not need to inject the scope as you use the controller-as syntax.

For further reading to controller-as I recommend
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md